# How to create and event on Meetup using theire REST API?

Tags: ios, rest, meetup

I am trying to use [meetup apis](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/). I have API key, Secret key and consumer key.

I can use the get events API and get all the public events meetups. but In my application I am allowing my users to create an event and that will be uploaded on meetup server using Meetup REST APIs. However I search for their docs and I found one API to create and event but it is asking for Group id as compulsory parameter.

I don't know where to get that group id or any other way to create an event there.

Please help me if someone tried it before.